# Class extension inside a playground

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I have a UIVIew subclass in my playground sources folder (its a Public class) and I'm trying to only put a portion of this class into my main playground file as an extension.

When I declare the following in my playground

```
public extension SortingAlgorithmView {

    public func typeTest() {
        print("dfasfndjasfasfdasfdasf test ")
    }
}
```

and then inside my subclass I call typeTest() it tells me there is no function with the name typeTest.

Comment: The point of this is that I want this code to be visible and able to be manipulated in my playground

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The interactive pages do not run alongside the source files; the source files are compiled first and then imported into your playground pages (which is why you need to make everything `public`).  This makes them much faster since they can be compiled just once instead of interpreted every time, but it also means they cannot reference the code in the playground pages.

If you want to access the extension from the source files, you'll have to put it in a source file.  The source files cannot access the interactive content.

Answer (score 4):

This works fine for me....

**EDIT:** OK, give this a try - again, works fine for me...

// extFuncs.swift --- in the sources folder

```
import UIKit

public extension SortingAlgorithmView {

    public func typeTest() {
        print("dfasfndjasfasfdasfdasf test ")
    }
}

public class SortingAlgorithmView: UIView {

}
```

// a page in the Playground

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let view = SortingAlgorithmView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 600, height: 600))
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

view.typeTest()

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

Comment: It doesn't work when class is in a source file and the extension is in the playground's main page.

Comment: How are you importing the source file? Do you have a "runnable" example?

Comment: The source file is in the playground's Sources directory.

Comment: OK - check the EDIT in my answer.

Comment: The OP wants the extension to be in the main playground page, yet accessible from the source file.

Comment: Oh.... `public class SortingAlgorithmView: UIView {}` in a main playground page, but creating an extension to it in a source file? Yeah, wouldn't expect that to work.

Comment: Actually, now I think I understand... view subclass in sources... extension to that class in playground page... call that extension from within that class? Again, no, wouldn't expect that to work... @NobodyNada 's initial answer said it all.